# How to make a fixed menu in header, appear over both the header and content in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, hide, z-index

I'm building a website which is still very much in process, but I'm stuck on something I can't figure out.

The website is currently visible on http://adhoc.fiberspa.nl
I'm developing mobile first, so it looks best if you shrink the browser screen when viewing in a browser.
When you view this in a browser, and click the menu button (top right) a menu slides in. The menu is still unstyled, but the point is that it nicely slides in on top of everything.

If you view the same website on a mobile device using chrome the Menu also slides in, on top of the header, but hides beneath the content. I noticed that it works fine on my mobile on firefox.

From reading I figured out it has something to do with fixed elements having their own z-index stacks.. so I can't use z-index to fix the problem. Possibly I have to change the entire structure of my document but I can't figure it out.

What I have is a page with a fixed header and footer. I somehow want a menu that slides in from the top, appearing over the header and over the content, when clicking the menu button.

Comment: I have tried the menu using a wide variety of browsers (including Chrome for Android, which I assume you are using) and all of them display it flawlessly. Could you please be more explicit about the software you are using (OS, version)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's very interesting.. the only browser I can't seem to get it to work on is Chrome on my android.. apparently version 42.0.2311.111 .. on Android 4.4.2

Comment: Additionally: If it's easier I'd be happy to have it drop down from beneath the header instead of the top of the page, but I definitely can't seem to make that happen, since my header is not fixed height.

Comment: The menu doesn't seem to be working _at all_ right now. Are you editing it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was only editing local. Should be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting a working version of what I was after using JQuery:

I made the menu fixed to the right and above the page on page load.

I used JQuery to calculate the height of the header when the menu button is clicked and move it down to that position, and back up when the button, menu, or page is clicked again.

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.adhocTheme = {
attach: function (context, settings) {


$('#l-navbutton').click(function () {
     var menu = $('.l-region--navigation');
     menu.css('top', $('.l-header').outerHeight() + "px");
     if(!menu.hasClass('show'))
        menu.addClass('show');
     else   
        {menu.removeClass('show'); menu.css('top', "0px");}
});

$('.l-region--navigation, .l-main, .l-footer').click(function () {
     var menu = $('.l-region--navigation');

     if(menu.hasClass('show'))
        {menu.removeClass('show'); menu.css('top', "0px");}
    });
  }
};
}(jQuery));
```

I added CSS for the slide down animation.

```
.l-region--navigation{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #cccccc; // Old browsers
  @include filter-gradient(#cccccc, #cccccc, vertical); // IE6-9
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  #cccccc 0%,#ededed 62%,#cccccc 100%));
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
  @include span (6 of 9);
  @include bleed($grid-padding);
 }

 .l-region--navigation.show{
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
 }
```

I gave my header a z-index of 100 to ensure the menu slides down beneath it and not over it. All in all this works beautifully!

If I did not want it to slide down from beneath the header, but over the header as in my original question, it would now work by having it slide from -200px to 0px, instead of to the header height and removing the z-index from the header. I had that first, but I like this better.